# About linear recurrence sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations, bilinear-form

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$,$\{b_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$,$\{c_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be three complex sequences and satisfy
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\sum_{k=0}^2\alpha_ka_{n+k}=0,\\
&&\sum_{k=0}^4\beta_kb_{n+k}=0,\\
&&b_n^2=c_na_n-c_{n-1}a_{n+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
for any $n$, where $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are some constants satisfying $\alpha_i=\alpha_{2-i}$, $\beta_i=\beta_{4-i}$.

Let us assume $a_n$,$b_n$,$c_n$are not constant sequences and $\alpha_k$,$\beta_k$,$\gamma_k$ are not always zeros.

Please try to prove that there exist nonzero constants $\gamma_k$, $k=0,1,\cdots8$ so that $\sum_{k=0}^8\gamma_kc_{n+k}=0$ hold for any $n$.

I want to know how to solve the above problem, or what knowledge should be used?

Thanks!

Comment: It certainly works with $\gamma_k=0$ for all $k$. Do you want some additional condition to be satisfied for the $\gamma_k$?

Comment: This is too trivial. Let us assume $a_n$,$b_n$,$c_n$are not constant sequences and $\alpha_k$,$\beta_k$,$\gamma_k$ are not always zeros.

Comment: Maybe we can firstly consider the special case: $\alpha_0=\alpha_2=1$， $\alpha_1=-3$, $\beta_0=\beta_4=1$, $\beta_1=\beta_3=-9$, $\beta_2=16$.

Comment: Just curious, what is the motivation behind this problem?

Comment: It is motivated by evaluating Hankel determinants by use of an integrable system. If this problem is solved, many results may be obtained. I'm glad that you are intersted in. Keep in touch please.